# How can I play an animation backwards in Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation

I have an animation where a box fades from its original colour to yellow, but I want to reverse this so that when the page loads, the box is initially yellow, but then fades to its original colour. The original colour is variable, so I can't just hardcode the animation in reverse.

Here's the animation trigger:

```
animations: [
    trigger('highlight', [
        state('true', style({
            'background-color': '#edf514'
        })),
        transition('* => true',
            animate('0.8s')
        )
    ])
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wildcard "*". See that you can use `:enter` to the "load"

```
animations: [
    trigger("fadeAnimation", [
      transition(":enter", [
        style({'background-color': 'yellow' }), //before start the animation background-color:yellow
        animate("5000ms", style({ 'background-color': '*' })) //animate to original background-color
      ]),
      transition('*=>true', [
        style({'background-color': 'yellow' }),
        animate("2000ms", style({ 'background-color': '*' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Your .html

```
<span id="word-carousel"
      [@fadeAnimation]="toogle"  (@fadeAnimation.done)="toogle=false">hello</span>
<button [disabled]="toogle" (click)="toogle=true">click</button>
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-draypz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)